# Reinstall Debian, keep conf and programs

Tags: debian, troubleshooting

I am having trouble to login on the GUi (gdm3). I can login in a prompt in this machine and connect to the internet (it's a fast connection).

Could I just run a command and reinstall the system and not bother with trouble shooting?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall gdm3.
Just run
`apt-get purge gdm3 && apt-get install gdm3`